# How to clone repo gitlab in remote server by gitlabrunner without add ssh key to remote machine

Tags: ssh, gitlab

I have a repo : git@gitlab.com/.....git

I have a gitlab runner can connect to remote server

File gitlab-ci.yml:

```
test-ssh:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - shell
  rules:
    - if: $CURRENT_JOB == 'deploy'
      when: on_success
  before_script:
    - chmod 400 $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
  script:
    - echo "Test ssh"
    - whoami
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.xxx.xxx.xxx "pwd && whoami && git clone git@gitlab.com:........git"
```

Result:

```
remote:
remote: ========================================================================
remote:
remote: ERROR: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.

remote:
remote: ========================================================================
remote:
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I don't wanna create ssh key in remote server then add deploy keys.

So, Is there any other way ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, you can push by https and not ssh protocol.

First set the config for the current user.
What we did is we created a user which performs all CI actions., created a token for this user. and push via this user only during the CI actions.

you will need to set up access token.

```bash
# Set config for user details
git config user.email "$GITLAB_USER_EMAIL"
git config user.name "$GITLAB_USER_LOGIN"

# Declare token
TOKEN=<my_token>

# set up git new remote.
git remote add new_origin https://oauth2:$TOKEN@gitlab.com/$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE/$CI_PROJECT_NAME.git 

# push.
git add .
git commit -m "your commit"
git push new_origin
```